# Set minuteinterval for native iOS Date-TimePicker

Tags: codenameone

Is there any way to set the minuteinterval for the Date-Time-Picker-Component in codenameone, when the native Picker-Element is used on an iOS device? I saw that you can do so when developing a native app directly in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

No. We're trying to shift to the lightweight mode where we will offer better control.

We found it very hard to keep up with the basic builtin functionality. So adding auxiliary functionality to the native picker is probably untenable. In the long term.

I don't think this is exposed in the lightweight picker but it should be relatively easy to add if you file an RFE.

Comment: I would like to file a RFE - but how do I do so?

Comment: File an issue here: http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/new
You can prefix it with RFE: to be clear. It's best to reference this thread but include all the details in it because stackoverflow posts sometimes get deleted. If it's easy we might sneak it into 5.0 but since that date is pretty close now it might go into 6.0